# NSDateFormatter return nil date for specify date strings

Tags: nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am trying to convert a string to date but NSDateFormatter returns nil for a specific date. In the code below all string are converted to Date except for date2 and date7. Any pointers as to what is wrong? Thanks

```
let date1 = "Jan 01, 1941"
        let date2 = "Oct 01, 1941"
        let date3 = "Oct 13, 1941"
        let date4 = "Sep 30, 1941"
        let date5 = "Mar 31, 1941"
        let date6 = "Oct 02, 1941"
        let date7 = "Oct 01, 1941"
        
        let dateStringFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateStringFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd, yyyy" //Using custom
        dateStringFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        let date_1 : Date? = dateStringFormatter.date(from: date1)
        let date_2 : Date? = dateStringFormatter.date(from: date2)
        let date_3 : Date? = dateStringFormatter.date(from: date3)
        let date_4 : Date? = dateStringFormatter.date(from: date4)
        let date_5 : Date? = dateStringFormatter.date(from: date5)
        let date_6 : Date? = dateStringFormatter.date(from: date6)
        let date_7 : Date? = dateStringFormatter.date(from: date7)
        print("\(String(describing: date_1)),\n\(String(describing: date_2)),\n\(String(describing: date_3)),\n\(String(describing: date_4)),\n\(String(describing: date_5)),\n\(String(describing: date_6)),\n\(String(describing: date_7))")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above problem can be solved by setting the date property on DateFormatter. The Date can be current system date.